# Firebase notifications issue with iOS in Testflight

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have the following problem:
I am trying to add Firebase notifications to an iOS app. I followed all the steps and it is working as expected when I build the app with XCode. The problem is when I upload the app, download it from testflight and try to send notifications. For some reason I cannot figure out is not working. When I go to firebase console and try to send a notification it shows "Invalid APN's certificate. Check the certificate in settings". The weird thing is that it works fine when I build the app on the iPhone directly from xcode.

Answer (score 1):

If your TestFlight app is not receiving push notification but is receiving notification only when running via Xcode then you have not uploaded the APN’s certificate to firebase console, as error suggests you.
Go to the Firebase console, select Settings and then the tab Cloud Messagging, then you can upload your APN’s certificate.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was that the certificate we had it was just for development, we did not have a production certificate, just added that and started working.

Answer (score 1):

When setting the device token to firebase in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken change is to .prod (If using production) or to .sandbox (If using development)

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.prod) // Here change to .prod or .sandbox
}
```